# Rails fixtures get table names wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fixtures

I have a `roles` table, a `permissions` table, and to join them in a many-to-many relationship a `roles_permissions` table.

In the `roles.yml` file I have this:

```
admin:
  name: admin
  permissions: create_user, edit_user, view_all_users
```

In the `permissions.yml` I have:

```
create_user:
  name: create_user
  description: Create a new user

edit_user:
  name: edit_user
  description: Edit any user details

view_all_users:
  name: view_all_users
  description: View all users
```

Now `rake test` gives me errors saying `no such table: permissions_roles: DELETE FROM "permissions_roles"`

When I comment out the line in `roles.yml` that specifies the admin permissions then the errors go away.

It looks like the fixtures are assuming the joining table is named `permissions_roles` when it's actually named `roles_permissions`

How do I tell it the right table name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, the join table name between two tables is named alphabetically.

So, the join table between `roles` and `permissions` should be named `permissions_roles`.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to create the table `permissions_roles`** instead of `roles_permissions`, or set the table in the options(`:join_table`):

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, join_table: "roles_permissions"
```

**#has_and_belongs_to_many**:

> Unless the join table is explicitly specified as an option, it is guessed using the **lexical order** of the class names. So a join between Developer and Project will give the default join table name of “developers_projects” because “D” precedes “P” alphabetically

Read more [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many).

Comment: But I didn't use `has_and_belongs_to_many` I used `has_many` with `:through` to set up the relationship.

Comment: So your `:through` should be the `roles_permissions` model

Comment: it is, but the YAML file for the fixtures doesn't seem to pick this up