# rails YAML: NOT NULL constraint failed in joining table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, yaml, rails-activerecord

Rails 4.2
I have set up a `Role` model and a `Permission` model which relate many-to-many with each other through another model `RolesPermission` I use the `has_many` with `:through` to relate the models.

`RolesPermission` has a table name of `permissions_roles` because of [Rails convention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389375/rails-fixtures-get-table-names-wrong) I renamed it from `roles_permissions` with a migration, and I put this in the model class:

```
self.table_name = "permissions_roles"
```

I set up fixtures for testing

In roles.yml I have

```
admin:
  name: admin
  permissions: create_user
```

and in permissions.yml I have

```
create_user:
  name: create_user
  description: Create a new user

edit_user:
  name: edit_user
  description: Edit any user details

view_all_users:
  name: view_all_users
  description: View all users
```

now when I run `rake test` every test gets this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:     
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: 
SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:
permissions_roles.created_at: INSERT INTO "permissions_roles" ("role_id", "permission_id") VALUES (135138680, 204622624)
```

when I remove the permission from the admin role in the YAML the error goes away.

What's going on?

EDIT

The joining table looks like this in the schema:

```
create_table "permissions_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "role_id"
  t.integer  "permission_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gradually reached the conclusion that it's not possible to do what I want to do in the way I'm trying to do it.

I see that in rails fixtures I can't take advantage of relationships that in ActiveRecord use the `:through` label

firstly this is evidenced by the fact it assumes a certain name for the joining table, which is the name it would have if it was a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship as seen in [another question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31389375/rails-fixtures-get-table-names-wrong), and secondly *this* question shows that it also assumes the joining table has no `created_at` column, which would also be the case if the relationship was `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Since rails fixtures don't support the convenience syntax when the relationship uses `:through` I must either put the relationship fixtures in the roles_permissions.yml file or I must simplify the relationship in my models by using `has_and_belongs_to_many`.

Answer (score 0):

Fill up `created_at` in the `create_user` permission. You are probably breaking database level validation on the field created_at (it can not be null).

> SQLite3::ConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   permissions_roles.created_at:

Comment: Your answer, though not complete, has certainly given me a lot of clarity on what's going on. It looks like when the fixtures are being set up it assumes the joining table doesn't have the created_at column.